# Adding outboundRules breaks my website in azure

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, sendy

I have a website in azure with a custom domain (I'm trying to install [sendy](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingSendyAPHPAppOnWindowsAzureToSendInexpensiveNewsletterEmailViaAmazonSES.aspx)), the issue is when the site renders from that custom domain all the HTML links in the content are pointing to mysite.azurewebsites.net

SO I decided to rewrite the HTML content to point to the correct domain, like subdomain.mysite.com but when I add the outbound rule basically the site breaks sending me this message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

I enabled the trace the diagnostic logs but I haven't found anything relevant for now.

my guess is that azure enables by default httpcompression causing the issue, because you can't do HTML rewrite when using compression.

this is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

       <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>

    <rewrite>
     <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Rewrite HTML" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
          <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script"
                 pattern="mysite.azurewebsites.net" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="subdomain.mysite.com" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>

      <rules>

        <rule name="Sendy all" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Sendy: link tracker" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^l/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="l.php?i={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Sendy: open tracker" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^t/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="t.php?i={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Sendy: web version" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^w/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="w.php?i={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Sendy: unsubscribe" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^unsubscribe/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="unsubscribe.php?i={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Sendy: subscribe" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^subscribe/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="subscribe.php?i={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: what your link looks like in your html code. As I test on my side, but i haven't occur your issue. Could you please tell how to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the URL compression fixed the issue.

basically, this configuration does the trick

```
<system.webServer>
   <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```